# ASP.net website don't execute the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have an asp.net website with c# and it was deployed on local network. it is working well, but sometimes all the buttons on the web form don't execute the code behind until I open a new tab in the browser and visit the main page of the website , then return to the previous tab and press the button again then the code will be executed correctly !!

do you have any solution for my problem?

Comment: Look in your browser console for any JavaScript errors. They may prevent the buttons from executing the postback script.

Comment: Actually, this also seems like it could be an issue specific to your computer. It's certainly strange behavior. Have you tried in alternate browsers on alternate computers?

Comment: I am using google chrome. Should I prevent javaScript form running?

Comment: No, there's no reason to do that. If there is an error in your code, then it should be fixed. With the postback model in ASP.NET Web Forms, I'm not sure your application will still work without JavaScript enabled.

Comment: I am sure that the problem not in my computer because many computers in the local network face the same problem!

Comment: Yeah, because as he said - repeatedly - and you ignore: fix your javascript error. It is not like browser have no debugging support -- it is 2014, not 1980.

Comment: how can I fix the javaScript error (if it is exist) ?

Comment: can this problem be "session time out" issue?

Comment: please note that the page don't show any error, when I press the buttons the web page is reloaded and the code is't executed !!

Comment: @hilda You need to look at your browser console. Right click the page and select "Inspect Element", then select the "Console" tab. That will show you any JavaScript errors.

Comment: there is no errors ! but if so , how can I fix it?

Comment: If its C# code-behind on postback of a form what would JavaScript have to do with it?

Comment: 1) Check Windows event log for ASP.NET exceptions, 2) Install Fiddler to inspect the traffic between browser and server. (3) You might also look at installing Elmah).

Comment: can you explain your solution in details (step by step), please?

Comment: Is this a web site (File->New Web Site), or a Web Application Project (File->New Project)?

Answer (score 0):

First goto extension manager and install nuget package manager if you dont already have one. Then goto tools tab you will find nuget manager there, search for elmah and install it. 
Follow this link for setting it up and see if you are getting any errors.

http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you , I will try this and tell you the result